# How to send keystrokes over internal network?

Tags: networking, keyboard, remote-control

Anyone know of a small, lightweight solution to send keystrokes from one PC to another PC over an internal network?  I want to be able to send all types of keystrokes, including the modifier keys and the Windows key.

Not looking for a remote access solution, but something that will just send keystrokes to another machine.

The computers are running Windows 7.

Comment: What operating systems are you running on your network?

Comment: Are you looking for a keylogger? (program that runs in background that captures and records keystrokes, stores them in a "log" and periodically sends the log over LAN) Or are you looking at sending the keystrokes in realtime? BTW this is most usually associated with malware / spyware :-/

Comment: http://mobilemouse.com/

Comment: @Julien That is an iOS application to send keystrokes to a PC. White Phoenix is looking for a PC to PC solution. If Mobile Mouse supports PC to PC, please elaborate.

Comment: Sorry, missed the PC to PC part.  Get the android version of mobile mouse and use bluestacks to run it on windows.  Clunky!

Comment: @iglvzx Windows 7 to Windows 7.  Sorry I forgot to mention that - will clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For windows to windows, [mouse without borders](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27589) works well, and simply. Despite the name it does keyboard as well

Answer (score 3):

[Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) lets you share a mouse and keyboard between multiple computers. It's not as general as what you might be looking for, but it might be good enough.